# Regular expressions. Get numbers from txt between <p></p> tags

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I try get a numbers (ONLY) between tags in Sublime Text text editor with regexp, but it not work

```
(?<=<p>).*(?=</p>) 
<p>abcdefg 1234.5 hijklmnop.</p></br>
```

is works to full text between

```
([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*)
```

is works for numbers and to all text blocks and other tags.

```
(?<=<p>)([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*) (?=</p>) - Is not works
```

How to combine these two expressions into one?

Me need it for massive changes style of numbers

Thanx

Comment: I am not sure, but [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/mD4qY0/1) may be of help if you have multiple numbers inside a `<p>` tag.

Comment: ([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*)(?=[^<p>]*</p>)

Comment: This one above is definitely not what you want.

Comment: but, seems, it work) editor allocates only numbers between the tags <p> now. what is wrong? king thanks for answers :)

Comment: It won't work if you have the letter `p` after the number. You can use `([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*)(?=[^<>]*</p>)` in this case. Or `([0-9]*(?:\,[0-9]+)?)(?=[^<>]*</p>) `. Or,  this one is clearer: `([0-9]*[,.]?[0-9]+)(?=[^<>]*<\/p>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this regex:

```
[0-9]*,?[0-9]+(?=[^<>]*<\/p>)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD4qY0/4)

- `[0-9]*` - 0 or more digits (to allow `,001` values)
- `,?` - Optional separator `,`
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?=[^<>]*<\/p>)` - A lookahead checking we are inside a `<p>` tag (there is mot closing `</p>` tag ahead).

However, if you have tags inside a `<p>` tag, you will need to use lazy matching with:

```
[0-9]*,?[0-9]+(?=(?:(?!<\/?p\b)[\s\S])*<\/p>)
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD4qY0/5)

Comment: I take off my hat. merci

Comment: but this expression stops when inside <p> it encounters , with another tag, <a> for example

Comment: `[0-9]*,?[0-9]+(?=(?:(?!<\/?p\b)[\s\S])*<\/p>)` does not. Technically, even if `<a>` tag is inside `<p>`, we are still inside `<p>`. Else, there is no way to check all numbers inside `<p>`-only tag with regex.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If  my answer works for you, please consider accepting.

Comment: Yes, it works fine! and, just in case - this is a best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using your desired patterns, you need to wrap the numeric pattern match with the wild card matches (except they are non-greedy here) you used in the first pattern:

```
(?<=<p>).*?([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*).*(?=</p>)
```

Comment: thank you) after this questions i found to write so
([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*)(?=[^<p>]*</p>) 
seems, it work!)

Comment: @n0mad: it seems but it's false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
(?<=<p>\D*?)\d+(?=\D*?</p>)
```

That is: In a lookbehind, assume `<p>` followed by 0 or more non-digits (non-greedy). Match any number of digits (but at least one), then assume (lookahead) non-digits potentially following (non-greedy), and necessarily a `</p>`.

I'm *pretty sure* though that what you want to achieve can be done simpler, without all this mess.

Now that I think about it, I think I remember Sublime's regex engine having limitations about quantifiers in lookaheads...

Comment: thank you for answer! my sublimetext2 doesnt want to understand your
regexp. but this work fine, seems:
([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*)(?=[^<p>]*</p>)

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, but ok. At least make that `([0-9]*\,?[0-9]*)(?=[^<]*</p>)`